# Client's udpserver don't response

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy

My server form has stringgride that accept only 4 tcp connected user
For this purpose, I put udpclient in my server and udpserver in clients

In tcp-onconnect event in server form :

```
   //Server Side has udp client
 procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin

      //when fifth user want to connect to tcpserver 
      //server first ensure at list one of the 4 connected user in grid has disconnected
      //by send udp broadcast to 4 user
      //but in this timeout None of these users do not respond , Although still connected

      IdUDPClient1.Broadcast('IP', 1718);
      For i:=1 To 4 Do
      begin
       IPList.Add(IdUDPClient1.ReceiveString(200););
      end;
end;


//Client Side has udp server
procedure TForm1.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(Sender: TObject; AData: TStream;
    ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
 //
 ip:=GetipAddress();
 ABinding.SendTo(ABinding.PeerIP, ABinding.PeerPort, ip[1], Length(ip));
end;
```

I run ethereal in client  to check network and saw udp massage send from server to client but client do not respond.

Please help me what's my code problems

Comment: You did not show your client code that receives the UDP broadcast. But why are you using UDP at all? TIdTCPServer has a MaxConnections property, and you should use TCP keepalives/heartbeats to detect dead TCP clients.

Comment: i first use tcp but didn't work,i use tcpclient in onconnect event  tcpserver but didn't work

Comment: it's Edited @RemyLebeau

Comment: Just saying "it doesn't work" says nothing at all about the actual problem you are having with it. You need to provide actual details if you want people to help you.

Comment: i use tcp Instead udp , but get error , connection close gracefully and client doesn't response

Comment: Connection closed gracefully is a perfectly normal error in TCP. Sounds like you were simply not handling it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your `TIdUDPServer.OnUDPRead` event handler does not have the correct signature, not even close. `TIdUDPServer` does not use `TIdPeerThread` at all, only `TIdTCPServer` does.  You need to do something more like this instead:

Server:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
  //when fifth user want to connect to tcpserver 
  //server first ensure at list one of the 4 connected user in grid has disconnected
  //by send udp broadcast to 4 user
  //but in this timeout None of these users do not respond , Although still connected

  IPList.Clear;
  IdUDPServer1.Broadcast('IP', 1718);
  Sleep(1000);
end;

procedure TForm1.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(Sender: TObject; AData: TStream; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  S: String;
begin
  if AData.Size > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(S, AData.Size);
    AData.ReadBuffer(S[1], AData.Size);
    IPList.Add(S);
  end;
end;
```

Client:

```
procedure TForm1.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(Sender: TObject; AData: TStream; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  S: String;
begin
  if AData.Size > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(S, AData.Size);
    AData.ReadBuffer(S[1], AData.Size);
  end;
  if S = 'IP' then
  begin
    S := ABinding.IP;
    if (S = '') or (S = '0.0.0.0') then
      S := GStack.LocalAddress;
    ABinding.SendTo(ABinding.PeerIP, ABinding.PeerPort, S[1], Length(S));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: why your server side has IdUDPServer1UDPRead? ,my server side has udp client and client side has udpserver

Comment: I meant to show `TIdUDPServer` being used on both sides. The reference to `TIdUDPClient` was a typo. I have fixed it. As for why `TIdUDPServer` is used server-side is because the client responses are asynchronous, which `TIdUDPClient` is not well suited to handle. Because UDP is connectionless, a `TIdUDPServer` can talk to another `TIdUDPServer`, unlike TCP.

Comment: i use this , but doesn't answer , when server broadcast IdUDPServer1UDPRead client side event doesn't excuted , WHY?

Comment: only 'IP' word save in IPList ,  WHY?

Comment: The broadcast is likely not going over the network, or the clients are not on the same subnet. Use Wireshark to verify. The server-side `TIdUDPServer` is receiving its own broadcast. I still suggest you drop UDP and use TCP keepalives instead.

Comment: help me to use tcp instead udp